# Discord.py delete custom emojis

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, emoji

I have a discord bot that adds custom emojis. I want it to remove all emojis it added when it is removed from a server. I am trying to use the emoji.delete() function from [the API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#emoji) but am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stefon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Stefon/PycharmProjects/testscrape/testscrape.py", line 750, in on_guild_remove
    await emoji.delete()
  File "C:\Users\Stefon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\emoji.py", line 189, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_custom_emoji(self.guild.id, self.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

My code:

```
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    print('Removed from guild')
    # Get all emojis in the guild
    emojis = guild.emojis

    # Get emoji names for all emojis added by the bot
    img_names = []
    for f in os.listdir('img'):
        img_names.append(f.split('.')[0])

    for emoji in emojis:
        # Remove the first word before an underscore and check if the resulting name is in the name of images
        temp_name = emoji.name.split('_')[1:]
        temp_name = '_'.join(temp_name)
        # If the emoji is one generated by the bot, remove it.
        if temp_name in img_names:
            print('Deleting emoji ' + temp_name)
            await emoji.delete()
    print('Done removing emojis..')
```

I suspect this is because I am attempting to remove the emotes after the bot has been removed from the server. If so, is there any other way I can delete all emotes on removal?

Answer (score 0):

```
async def de(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    for Emoji in ctx.guild.emojis:
        await Emoji.delete()
```